# Inheritance inside Classes Python3

Tags: python, inheritance, nested

I need something like this

```
class Parent(object): 
    class Base(object):
        def __init__(self, a, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b


    class Derived(Base):
        def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            super(Derived,self).__init__(a, b)
            self.c = c

        def doit():
            pass

parent = Parent()
derived = parent.Derived(x,y,z)
derived.doit()
```

When I try to run this, i get this following error: `NameError: name 'Derived' is not defined`

I tried with 'Base' in the place of 'Derived' in `super()` - didn't help

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What's the point of that nesting?

Comment: Would it not just be better to declare `Derived` inside of `Parent`?

Comment: what python version are you running? is it not enough to go with super().__init__ ?

Comment: You are trying to call `Derived` inside the `Parent` class, wich doesn't exist, and you get the NameError. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @daniel: the 'Derived' object should not exist without a 'Parent' object. A remotely similar example is 'Note' written in a paper, cannot exist without 'Paper' object.

Comment: @games braniac: that's what i am planning to implement finally. I was testing the 'Derived', when i tried to create its instance i got this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixing 'Derived' with 'Parent.', made it. As I already have commented on the question. This is just for experimenting with the 'Derived' class. But I am still wondering how the, 'class Derived(Base):' is fine (without 'Parent.' prefix for 'Base' class)

```
class Parent(object): 
    class Base(object):
        def __init__(self, a, b):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b


    class Derived(Base):
        def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            super(Parent.Derived,self).__init__(a, b)
            self.c = c

        def doit():
            pass

parent = Parent()
derived = parent.Derived(x,y,z)
derived.doit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Class inheritance does not change the parent class. In this case your `Parent` class only contains the original `Base` class and not the derived class.

You can simply use monkey-patching to solve this problem,

```
class Parent(object): 
    pass


class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        super(Derived,self).__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c

    def doit(self):
        pass

Parent.Derived = Derived

parent = Parent()
x, y , z = 1, 1, 1
derived = parent.Derived(x,y,z)
derived.doit()
```